# How to get `data-listid` attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In browsers console i am getting the below html element after using `console.log` in jquery script.

```
<li class="fe_pui-autocomplete-box ui-draggable ui-sortable-helper" data-listid="latest_4604b40a-0492-49da-a86e-37f633501c2c" style="position: absolute; left: -561.812px; top: 98px; width: 456px; height: 14px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0;">.....</li>
```

I am using code like:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', 'li', function() 
{ 
console.log($(this)[0]); 
.....
```

How to get `data-listid` attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
console.log($(this)[0].attributes[1].value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use .attr to get any attribute value: use:

```
console.log($(this).attr("data-listid"));
```

OR

```
console.log($(this).data('listid'));
```

Comment: yes you need to just get the  listid attribute right?

Answer (score -1):

```js
console.log($('li').attr('data-listid')) //normally use .attr()
console.log($('li').data('listid')) //if you set the attr using .data() you get it using .data().
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="fe_pui-autocomplete-box ui-draggable ui-sortable-helper" data-listid="latest_4604b40a-0492-49da-a86e-37f633501c2c" style="position: absolute; left: -561.812px; top: 98px; width: 456px; height: 14px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0;">.....</li>
</ul>
```

1. Normally you can use .attr()
2. If you set the attr using .data() use need to use .data() to get it

ex.

you set the attr like

```
$('li').data('listid','adasdasdasdas') // use .data()
```